# How many formats of mail client's address book?

Tags: email, file, client, format

I want to develop a library to handle mail client’s address book. And, I know Microsoft Outlook’s address book’s format is *.pst. What about Mozilla thunderbird or others?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

PST isn't address book, it's archived email.

You could start by reading the source of [Apache Tika](http://tika.apache.org) which handles some formats.